# How to save fileds with base64 image in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios

How to save firstname, lastname and image (base64) in form with reactjs with axios?
please help me with sample code

Answer (score 0):

You can call the axios.post(url, data) to save data.

For example axios.post("/user", {firstname:"Don", lastname:"Joe", image:"..."});

Axios works with Promise. So you can check in there is an error writing:

```
axios.post("/user", {firstname:"Don", lastname:"Joe", image:"..."})
.then((result) => {
    console.log("Result is..", result);
}, (error) => {
    console.error("Error saving user data..", error, error.message);
});
```

When you work with base64 data the error could be on the server or probably you have converted an image to a wrong base64 string (so server cannot parse the base64 or the implemented checks could throw an exception).

Comment: how post nested json?

{
    "username":"joeman",
    "firstname":"joe",
    "lastname":"black",
    "vehicle":{
        "name":"bwv",
        "pelak":"12 b 34 653"
    },
    "image":"base64 image"
}

Comment: Exactly as in my answer. Axios want and URL and the payload: axios.post(URL, PayLoad)..

In your case: 
`axios.post("/user", { "username":"joeman", "firstname":"joe", "lastname":"black", "vehicle":{ "name":"bwv", "pelak":"12 b 34 653" }, "image":"base64 image" })`

"base64 Image" has to be a real and well formatted base 64 string.